# Button is clicked, but no js code is triggered

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, end-to-end, jest-puppeteer

I have a stepwizard where the next button triggers a post request before navigating to next the step.

```
    await page.click('[data-test-next-step]');
    await page.waitForSelector(['data-test-address-page']);
```

When I click on the button via `page.click(selector)` and `page.waitForSelector(next-page)` nothing happens. However, if I set a `waitFor(500)` prior to clicking on the next button, it works just fine.

Any idea what this could be?
I have already tried `waitUntil` and all the possible values we can pass to it, but no luck

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post relevant parts of your code? I think you can try `page.waitForSelector(selector)` instead waitfFor before `page.click(selector)` to make sure the button  is accesible

Comment: Updated post with code, although the code was already in the first paragraph

Comment: Following up the last comment could you try adding `await page.waitForSelector(['ddata-test-next-step']);` before click?

Comment: I do have this in my code, sorry I didn't include it above:

Comment: await page.waitForSelector(selector, { visible: true });
  await page.click(selector);